# A problem on permutation

Tags: permutations

**Question** :If there are $6$ periods in each working day of a school,in how many can one arrange $5$ subjects such that each subject is allowed at least one period?

*My solution:* ${^5P_5} *{^5P_1}=600$

Logic that I used is:out of 6 periods,5 periods are arranged  for $5$ subjects and the remaining one period is arranged for any of the $5$ subjects.

But my solution does not match with the one provided by textbook.Where is my mistake?

And is not it a combination's problem (since the order  of the arrangement of classes does not matter here)?

Comment: Your solution is counting duplicate arrangements.

Comment: Could you please explain?

Comment: Could you please explain the obscure statement "each subject is allowed at least one period"?

Comment: You are in school and there are periods such that in each period a particular subject is taught....here

Comment: One of the five subjects must appear twice, and you state the Question as a matter of "how many ways can one arrange" the subjects.  So I don't follow why "the order of the arrangement of classes does not matter here".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: The order of the subject matters since we are counting the ways to arrange the subjects.

Now since each subject must have at least one period, then clearly, *unless a free period is allowed*, one of the subjects will have two periods.

You must count the ways to:

- choose which is that doubled subject
- the ways to choose its two periods (they don't have to be adjacent), and then
- the ways to arrange four singletons among the remaining periods.

Multiply these three counts together.